# shell script to convert windows file to unix using dos2unix

Tags: python, linux, shell, unix, dos2unix

I'm writing a simple shell script to make use of `dos2unix` command to convert Windows-format files to Unix format as and when it arrives in my folder.

I used to use `iconv` in the script and automate it to get one encoding converted to the other.  But now I need to use `dos2unix` instead of `iconv`.

I don't want the original file to be overwritten (it must be archived in the `archive` folder).  This was straightforward with `iconv`; how can I do the same with `dos2unix`?

This is my script:

```sh
cd /myfolder/storage
filearrival_dir= /myfolder/storage
filearchive_dir=/myfolder/storage/archive

cd $filearrival_dir
echo " $filearrival_dir"
for file in File_October*.txt
do
    iconv -f UTF16 -t UTF8  -o "$file.new" "$file"   &&
    mv -f "$file.new" "$file".`date +"%C%y%m%d"`.txt_conv &&
    mv  $file $filearchive_dir/$file
 done
```

The above  looks for files matching `File_Oct*.txt`, converts to the desired encoding and renames it with the timestamp and `_conv` at the end. This script also moves the original file to the archive.

How can I replace `iconv` in the above script with `dos2unix` and have the files archived and do the rest just like I did here?

Answer (score 2):

You can "emulate" `dos2unix` using `tr`.

`tr -d '\015' infile > outfile`

Answer (score 0):

If this is just about using `dos2unix` so it doesn't over-write the original file, just use

```
-n infile outfile
```

My recollection is that `dos2unix` writes UTF-8 by default, so you probably don't have to take any special action so far as encoding is concerned.